# About installing parallel software for win 10

Tags: windows

I am trying to install two clubhouse apps in my Windows 10 OS, so I have googled [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=How%20to%20install%20parallel%20software%20for%20win&newwindow=1&biw=1536&bih=754&sxsrf=AOaemvIEviluM5uLs4aYH1VFBb_RCV-4vQ%3A1633542328149&ei=uOBdYbq5CPyHjLsP6daBgAc&ved=0ahUKEwi69caxq7bzAhX8A2MBHWlrAHAQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=How%20to%20install%20parallel%20software%20for%20win&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBwgAEEcQsAMyBwgAEEcQsAMyBwgAEEcQsAMyBwgAEEcQsAMyBwgAEEcQsAMyBwgAEEcQsAMyBwgAEEcQsAMyBwgAEEcQsANKBAhBGABQgooBWKKLAWC3jQFoAXACeACAAegCiAHoApIBAzMtMZgBAKABAcgBCMABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz) and don't find out  have to install two same software as parallel. I know in android there is some parallel software like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lbe.parallel.intl&hl=en_US&gl=US) app, which you can have two same apps as parallel, but don't know which software could do it in windows.
Also, I guess it could be done by installing the [virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) and installing new windows or other OS On the  pc and the installation of every software that I like, but this solution take high CPU form my pc and needs high Hard Space (memory) so I like to have better solution, if possible.

**Update 1:**

Based of one answer, I have tried to find the `Clubdeck.Setupin.xxxx.exe` file in the `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Clubdeck` folder but don't find it, the folder contain are shown below:

[image]

So if possible, I updated the question to find out the location of the `Clubdeck.Setupin.xxxx.exe` file.

Thanks.

Comment: I think the keyword you are looking for is 'portable' and not 'parallel'. Portable apps basically save data 'locally' - from where the app executable is running. What windows app are you using for clubhouse? You didn't share a link...

Comment: Excuse me, my means is parallel, and the [clubdeck](https://www.clubdeck.app/) is the win10 app .

Comment: 'parallel' is an Android concept, not a windows one - that's why I directed you to the concept of 'portable'. Clubdeck doesn't look like an open-source project, but it does look like an Electron based app. By default it's data is stored in %APPDATA%\Clubdeck, I'm pretty sure you can trick it to store data in a different location. I'll play with it, will respond with an answer if I find a solution. in the meantime, this [search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Create+portable+version+of+any+windows+app) might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It seems [ClubDeck](https://www.clubdeck.app/) stores everything in `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Clubdeck`. So the trick to running multiple instances is to have it store it's data elsewhere.

The process described below worked for me. Note, I am not running the installer.

##### First Instance

1. Download the setup file from ClubDeck's site, currently it is `Clubdeck.Setup.1.6.7.exe`.
2. Open `Clubdeck.Setup.1.6.7.exe` in [7-Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/).
3. You will see that the entire app is stored inside a 7z archive named `app-64.7z`.
4. Extract this file, and then extract it's content into `D:\Clubdeck\app`
5. Create a batch file named `D:\Clubdeck\profile1.cmd` and copy-paste the content below:

   ```
   :: Change the value of USERPROFILE
   SET "USERPROFILE=%~dp0data\%~n0"
   :: Make sure the directory exists
   MKDIR "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming"
   :: Start ClubDeck with the new environment
   start "" /B "%~dp0\app\clubdeck.exe"
   ```
6. When executing the batch file, all data will now be stored under `D:\_\bin\Clubdeck\data\<profile name>`, effectively making ClubDeck a portable app.

##### Another Instance

Copying  `profile1.cmd` to another name, for example `profile2.cmd` you will be able to run another instance of ClubDeck with a completely different data store.

###### Disclaimer

Testing this has worked out for me right now, I can't guarantee that it will continue to do so.

[image: Screenshot showing 2 different instances of Clubdeck (one logged in, the other is not) running side by side]

Comment: Thanks, @Lockszmith for your answer. I have some problem about the above instruction which I have write about it in the question.

Comment: I've updated my answer, hopefully made it clearer